# Do I need to free wchar memory allocated when using 'new' or does delete[] also free it?

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, delete-operator

Trying to see the proper way to free memory, and I can't find a definitive answer. I'm sure it's out there, but I can't seem to find it and I'm a bit confused.

Here's what I'm doing. I create a new sStructUsers from sUsers, then I allocate memory for the username

```
    struct sStructUsers 
        {
        TCHAR *sName;
        };

    sStructUsers *sUsers = new sStructUsers[TOTALUSERS]();

    // Allocate memory for the TCHARs in sStruct
    for (INT k = 0; k < TOTALUSERS; k++)
        {
        sUsers [k].sName =  (TCHAR*)calloc(128,sizeof(TCHAR))
        }
```

Next, I do whatever work I need to do with the sName member

```
    // do work here
```

Now, to cleanup, do I do this:

```
    delete[] sUsers;
```

or do I do this?

```
    for (INT k = 0; k < TOTALUSERS; k++)
        {
        free(sUsers[k].sName);
        }
    delete[] sUsers?
```

I'm not sure if I need to free the memory or if delete[] would take care of it?

Comment: Don't combine -`alloc()` functions with `new`.

Comment: I have to allocate memory for sName somehow besides TCHAR sName[128]. That would eat up the stack.

Comment: What's wrong with `new TCHAR[128]`?

Comment: Both allocations would need to be `deallocated`. Calling `delete[ ]` on only `sUsers` will not free the memory allocated for the name as well. Why not use a `std::string` or a `std::unique_ptr` instead? Why complicate your life with manual memory management.

Comment: `sStructUsers *sUsers = new sStructUsers[TOTALUSERS]();`  -- You're using C++.  Why isn't this: `std::vector<sStructUsers> sUsers(TOTALUSERS);`?  Then `TCHAR *sName;` -- You're using C++.  Why isn't this: `std::basic_string<TCHAR> sName;`?  Or `std::wstring sName;` if this is a Unicode app and you no longer need to mess around with `TCHAR`.  Contrary to popular belief by newbies and non-C++ programmers, using pointers and dynamic memory all over the place does not make a C++ app look "professional" or "great".

Comment: I have found that my `std::vector<WCHAR>` memory allocated is not always freed, so my program has a leak. Now I have to do a .clear() and a .shrink_to_fit(). Ugh, may as well use WCHAR/calloc!?

Answer (score 5):

Don't use `new` at all if you can help it. In modern C++ in most cases `new` is not needed.
You can use `std::vector`, `std::array`, `std::string` (`std::basic_string<TCHAR>` maybe), `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`.

If you feel like you really need to use `new`, make special class which will handle this. I.e. for example make `new` in constructor and `delete` in destructor.

And of course, as was said in comments, never mix up new/delete with malloc/free. There is no need to use these functions in C++ at all, since this is remnants of C.

Edit: Added example, how this can be handled by class itself.

```
struct sStructUsers 
{
    const int MAX_NAME_SIZE = 128;
    sStructUsers()
    {
        sName = new TCHAR[MAX_NAME_SIZE];
    }
    ~sStructUsers()
    {
        delete sName;
    }
    TCHAR *sName;
};
```

Then you don't need any initialization/cleanup when using this class.

Note that you usually you don't need to do even this, you can define you class as this:

```
struct sStructUsers 
{
    std::basic_string<TCHAR> sName;
};
```

And have full `string` functionality for free. Or like this, if you really need a pointer:

```
struct sStructUsers 
{
    const int MAX_NAME_SIZE = 128;
    sStructUsers() : sName(new TCHAR[MAX_NAME_SIZE]) {}
    std::unique_ptr<TCHAR[]> sName;
};
```

Or, as I mentioned earlier, use other standard containers.

Comment: Can you show me an example of a contructor/destructor in a class to handle what I'm attempting to do?

Comment: Added in answer.

Comment: Thanks for that. **Question 1:** How would I reference `sUsers[1, 2, 3...x].sName` in my code if I used `std::basic_string<TCHAR> sName;`? **Question 2:** doesn't `sName = new TCHAR[MAX_NAME_SIZE];` take memory off of the heap?

Comment: 1. There is no difference in referring to object, it will be object of different type, i.e. `std::basic_string` vs char pointer. 1. Yes, memory allocated in heap as is the case with `basic_string`, but in case of `basic_string` you don't need to keep track of it and free it when memory no longer needed (or risk memory leak).

Answer (score 1):

Each allocation should be deallocated. By some code. As [sklott](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56870593/6655648) wrote, there are tools (containers and other classes) that do the work for you. If some other code does not do it, then your code should do the deallocation.

In short, you should call both `free(sUsers[k].sName)` and `delete[] sUsers`. As it stands, deleting[] `sStructUsers`s will not free pointers inside it.

(You could also modify `sStructUsers` so that its destructor does the deallocation, either directly or through a smart pointer.)

(To answerers and commenters who posted "never mix up new/delete with malloc/free", please kindle bash me with comments explaining why. It is always important to understand the rationale behind advice and best practices. *Update*: obviously you must not mix new+free, or malloc+delete, etc.; such functions must be properly paired lest you get heap corruption and leaks. The finer question is why not use new+delete for some allocations and malloc/calloc+free for others [finer still: CoTaskMemAlloc(), HeapAlloc(), VirtualAlloc() or other plataforms functions...]. )

Comment: Quote from cppreference.com on malloc(): `This function does not call constructors or initialize memory in any way. There are no ready-to-use smart pointers that could guarantee that the matching deallocation function is called. The preferred method of memory allocation in C++ is using RAII-ready functions std::make_unique, std::make_shared, container constructors, etc, and, in low-level library code, new-expression.`

Answer (score 1):

The comments and answers that are advising more preferable containers, more idiomatic C++, and more modern practices are all fine and well.

But your immediate question is answered by your second option

```
for (INT k = 0; k < TOTALUSERS; k++)
    {
    free(sUsers[k].sName);
    }
delete[] sUsers;
```

That will not leak memory. However your first option will leak because a mere `delete[]` of the array will not deallocate the heap memory of its elements.

In short, use `delete[]` for every `new[]`, and `free` for every `calloc`.

(Only then perhaps refactor to be closer to C++ than a mix of C and C++)

Comment: Ok, I will do a free() when I calloc the memory in combination with new and delete.